# When to use property lists (outside of simple table data use)? (iOS)

Tags: ios, property-list

I realise that property lists are a way to store relatively small amounts of data in a structured way and see clearly what a row in a list is composed of, so they might, for example, be used for table data to avoid hard coding long arrays or dictionaries. Just wondering what other uses they have for developers outside of this? I know they are used for configuration files created by Apple also. Just wondering are they worth learning too much more about. Are they employed much by iOSdevelopers out there and if so, when?

Edit: When to use over NSKeyedArchiver, NSUserDefaults, etc.? Just curious about when they are best taken off the shelf for use. Don't want to be using them for the sake of it. Like at a maximum of how many items in an array would you starting considering to use a plist?

Comment: They are XML with a schema.  There isn't much to learn.

Comment: Thanks, just want to know of common use cases when developers will bother creating one rather than hardcoding data in an array for example. Just trying to learn. Would appreciate if you can give an answer with use cases.